# Access Rank / Update Duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, sql-update, append

I have two columns in my output: Name of a person and associated ID number of this person. It can be that one name has assigned multiple IDs (while the IDs are always unique) - given that I need unique values for the names to upload somewhere, I would like to update the names with multiple IDs to be displayed as "Name.", "Name.." and so on.

I already made the query which shows purely the duplicated names with the unique IDs.

The amount of name duplicates differs from person to person.

Example-

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| B | 7 |
| C | 8 |
| C | 9 |

And I want this to be:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A. | 2 |
| A.. | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| B. | 5 |
| B.. | 6 |
| B... | 7 |
| C | 8 |
| C. | 9 |

Does anybody know an elegant way to do this?

Many thanks,
Daniela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have `string` function to repeat a character

[image: example table] [image: Result]

```
SELECT personName & STRING((SELECT COUNT(id) from table1 AS t1 
      WHERE table1.id >t1.id AND table1.personName = t1.personName),".") as [Name], ID
FROM table1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help! I get a type mismatch error though given that the ID is often not purely numeric (e.g. it can be L234 or Pseudo***). Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I've changed ID's in my Access table to text and it still works for me. Try to see maybe it will help? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/i-get-a-message-about-data-type-mismatch-c75b62ff-bcfd-4bb0-83f8-8129f372d59f

Comment: I was lying haha - It does indeed work like a charm, thank you very much, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @DVEF That's very nice Daniela could you please accept the answer or mark it as useful then :)?

Answer (score 0):

Try below query-

```
SELECT t.PersonName & (SELECT Count(*)
            from tblPersons as t2
            WHERE (t2.ID <= t.ID AND t2.PersonName = t.PersonName)
            ) AS Ranking, t.ID
FROM tblPersons AS t;
```

[image]

If you want show dot after name then use below query

```
SELECT t.PersonName & STRING((SELECT Count(*)
            from tblPersons as t2
            WHERE (t2.ID <= t.ID AND t2.PersonName = t.PersonName)
            ),".") AS Ranking, t.ID
FROM tblPersons AS t;
```

[image]

Comment: In that case `Name` column is sorted as shown on screenshot?